looking for pine script to trigger once when crossing a pivot point
cant understand why I get multiple triggers from the following code. even on the same bar in 1 case.  by using the not statement as as soon as the alert is triggered there should not be any trades until it is reset for the new day.       I do not want to wait for the bar to form, I want it as soon as as the price (close) crosses the PP
kind regards
newDay = bool(ta.change(time('D'))) t      = str.format_time(time, " HH:mm", "UTC+2")  

EMA_1 = ta.ema(close, emaL)  

// Variables creation  
var traded_today = false 
var traded_today1 = false  

if newDay     
    traded_today := false     
    traded_today1 := false  


if newDay and IsInSession and open >= PP and EMA_1 > vS1 and EMA_1 < close     
    startAboveP  := true   

P_Trade = open > PP and close <= PP  

longReady  = not traded_today and startAboveP 
longtrade = not traded_today1 and IsInSession and startAboveP and P_Trade

     
// ENTRY
if longReady
    traded_today := true



if longtrade
    traded_today1 := true
    alert("Buy "  + syminfo.ticker + " now " +  "\n TP1 " + str.tostring(vR1, format.mintick) + "\n SL " + str.tostring(vS1, format.mintick) + "\n Pivot_Buy" + "\n\n Time Stamp of trigger\n" + "\n\n Time of trade " + str.tostring(t) , alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    

